# Arriving at a different port of entry than specified in the Indian visa application?

Tags: visas, india, customs-and-immigration

When applying for my Indian visa, I had to state my point of entry (POE) among many other things.

The actual visa in the passport doesn't mention the POE, can I now change my mind and arrive in a different place? Or will they check on arrival and give me problems?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Nope, they don't care. I just checked with one of my British friends who went to India in 2010 - he specified port of entry as Delhi but flew in to Mumbai instead as he changed his itinerary. I think it's more of a formality really, since you'll be filling out a disembarkation form at the airport anyway specifying your entry details.